# How does TeX distinguish between variables and procedures?

Tags: tex-core

Every computer program evaluating anything has to distinguish between variables and procedures. This is a typical example from SICP:

```scheme
(define (eval exp env)
  (cond ((self-evaluating? exp) exp)
        ((variable? exp) (lookup-variable-value exp env))
        ((quoted? exp) (text-of-quotation exp))
        ((assignment? exp) (eval-assignment exp env))
        ((definition? exp) (eval-definition exp env))
        ((if? exp) (eval-if exp env))
        ((lambda? exp) (make-procedure (lambda-parameters exp)
                                       (lambda-body exp)
                                       env))
        ((begin? exp)
         (eval-sequence (begin-actions exp) env))
        ((cond? exp) (eval (cond->if exp) env))
        ((application? exp)
         (apply (eval (operator exp) env)
                (list-of-values (operands exp) env)))
        (else
         (error "Unknown expression type: EVAL" exp))))
```

If the expression is a variable it is looked up in the environment. And if the expression is an application it gets executed.

In TeX the following seems to assign a value to a variable:

```tex
\magnification=1200
```

But this is called a control sequence:

```tex
\input MS
```

It seems to me that a control sequence (an application) looks the same as a variable. How is it possible that the the evaluator in TeX can distinguish them? Is it because `\magnification` is not a variable but a accessor-function returning the value of the variable?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147620/discussion-on-question-by-ceving-how-does-tex-distinguish-between-variables-and); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: I've moved the comments here to chat: I have a feeling they could run for a bit ...

Answer (score 8):

In TeX, `\magnification` refers to the internal integer register `\mag`. You can use the value when TeX is looking for an integer, for instance

```
\count255=\mag
```

will store in the integer register `\count255` the current value of `\mag`.

<sub>The TeXbook would call `\mag` a “parameter”, but I believe that using “register” is clearer.</sub>

If TeX is *not* looking for an integer, then `\mag` will trigger the lookup, so that eventually TeX will store an integer in the register, so upon finding

```
\mag=1200
```

the stated value will be stored in the register. Actually, plain TeX provides `\magnification` that uses a similar syntax, but does more than setting `\mag`.

The same is true for every register: when TeX is looking for a <dimen>, say when you want to do `\kern`, you can type

```
\kern 1in
```

or

```
\kern \parindent
```

There's no distinction between variables and “procedures” in TeX. As shown before, register names can be used when a value is needed or they are the trigger for assigning a value, depending on the context.

Macro packages, for instance LaTeX, try to better separate the two aspects, so you say

```
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
```

instead of `\parindent=15pt` (or the more cryptic, but equally valid `\parindent15pt`). Or you can say

```
\setlength{\parindent}{2\parindent}
```

if you want to double the currently stored value for the parameter, but this is a particular programming style that cannot be enforced: if a user types in

```
\parindent=2\parindent
```

the effect is the same.

Conversely, `\input` is a primitive that triggers reading a file in order to feed the input token stream. Other primitives do other tasks. Sometimes it's a typesetting task, sometimes not.

Comparing TeX to other programming languages is a dead-end, I'm afraid.

Comment: @UlrichDiez You're perfectly right, the simplification was too strong.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I added a comment about “parameter” versus “register”.

Answer (score 6):

TeX is a filter: it transforms the input to the output. In normal (default) case, if the input includes `a` then the output includes `a`. But there is many exceptions. This is main difference from typical programming language by which we create a computer program for solving various tasks enabled by computer. These tasks are implemented typically as functions: elementary functions are based on system calls and other functions are already programed in libraries or by us. So, comparison between TeX and other programming languages isn't always possible.

The converting the input to the output by TeX is done at more levels: input processor (transforms input lines), token processor (generates tokens), expand processor (expands macros and expandable primitives), main processor (does assignments and typesetting). The heart is the main processor. It asks a single token from the expand processor and does something with the token in a loop. The loop body works in various contexts. In normal context, when main processor gets the token `a` then it prints the `a` (adds it to a build horizontal list of typesetting material, but this is not important now).

When the main processor in normal context gets a control sequence then it does something according to the actual meaning of the control sequence. If its meaning is a TeX primitive then a build-in procedure in TeX is run (you say "function" this case). For example, if its meaning is `\def`, then main processor goes to the "assigning macro" context. In this context, it switches off the expand processor and asks next tokens in given syntax

```
\def\sequence parameters{body}
```

If the last token of this syntax `}` is read then main processor assigns the meaning "macro" to the given control sequence, saves the parameters and body to the TeX memory and links the control sequence to this memory, switches on the expand processor and continues processing in the normal context.

If the meaning of already read token (in normal context) is a register, then main processor starts the context "assignment to the register" and asks the next tokens in this context until the value (with exactly given syntax `\register=value` or `\register value`) is fully scanned. Then the value is assigned and the context is return to normal.

Note that expanding macros and getting the value of registers (for printing, no for assigning) isn't business of main processor, the work is done by expand processor. The value of a register can be get using expandable primitive `\the`: expand processor gets a next token, it must have the meaning "register". Then the expand processor outputs the value of it (a sequence of tokens in given syntax).

Each defined control sequence have one of the following meanings: a register, a primitive command, a character constant, a font switcher, a macro. The expand processor and main processor behaves differently according to the actual meaning of the processed control sequence.

See also [TeX in a Nutshell](https://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for TeX in a Nutshell. The first section explains it already.

Comment: 'heard' -> 'head'? I really like this answer. It makes more sense of TeX than the TeX Book (which is great, but hard for me to grasp).

Comment: @cfr Pretty sure "heard" above is a typo for "heart" not "head". But the anatomy analogy can be confusing: IIRC Knuth calls it the "stomach" :D

Answer (score 3):

From ["TeX in a Nutshell" by Petr Olšák](https://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf):

> There are four types of meanings of control sequences:
>
> - register (primitive or declared)
> - primitive command
> - character constant
> - macro

TeX's syntax does not reflect this differences. By looking at the document source it is not possible to distinguish them. The difference is stored internally, when the control sequence gets defined. The way a control sequence gets defined specifies its type. And the hidden type information is used during the evaluation.

Comment: I did not find the phrase "character constant" in the TeXbook - what is a "character constant"? Besides <registerdef tokens> which probably might be referred to by the term "declared register", there are also <chardef tokens> and <mathchardef tokens> and <fontdef tokens> etc.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I added a link to the document: what it actually says is “…the control sequence can be a character constant (declared by \chardef or \mathchardef primitive command) or a font selector (declared by \font primitive command).”